# Webscrape Print to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm looking to print the output of this script to a new CSV.  I'm new to this and trying to understand the different pieces, but I've tried two different print methods (each of which work when I don't include the rest of my script).  Neither seem to be running?

Is there something off elsewhere? Or something I can't do here? Just not understanding why both work elsewhere.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
    len(dfs)
    for df in dfs:
        print(df)
        print('___________')
```

Also trying:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    len(dfs)
    for df in dfs:
        with open('pbptest.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(df)
        print(df)
        print('___________')
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want individual csv's.  If so, name the output separately.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    i = 1
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv(f'out_{i}.csv', index=False )
        i+=1
```

If you want all data in one csv, instead go for:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', index=False )
```